# UIScrollView page width does not match screen size

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, ios7.1

I'm trying to find an answer to a bizzare behavoiur ( I probably don't understad it ; / ) of UIScrollView on iOS 7.1)
This is the view hierarchy that i have:

- UIScrollView (width 1024 px)
  - pageHolder (UIView width 2048 px)
    - page1 (UIView)
    - page2 (UIView)

I add first page with frame (0,0, 1024, height) 
and second page with frame (1024, 0, 1024, height)
but this produces a huge gap (size of one page) between page 1 and 2 and i have no clue why..

if I set the origin.x of second page to 512 then i works fine but makes no sense to me ; / width of screen is 1024 so why would this work with 512 ?
( page1 frame (0,0,1024, height)
( page2 frame (512, 0, 1024, height)

any ideas ?

as far as code goes, this is really basic:
scrollView.contentSize = (2048, height)
pageHolder.size = (2048, height)
then simply adding subviews (pages) to pageHolder ...

Comment: Are you sure you're dealing with px and not pt? In general, your device will use points instead of pixels for measurements. When placing coordinates on an iOS device, do not account for screen density (retina 2x or 3x).

Comment: i guess it's pt after all but this doesn't change the problem - the width of page is correct (covers whole screen), problem lies with origin of each page (unless origin is given in different unit than width?)

Comment: If you set the width to `512`, what do you see?